# How to parse a list of dictionaries in Python 3

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I'm using python(requests) to query an API.   The JSON response is list of dictionaries, like below:

```
locationDescriptions = timeseries.publish.get('/GetLocationDescriptionList')['LocationDescriptions']


print(locationDescriptions[0])

{'Name': 'Test',
 'Identifier': '000045',
 'UniqueId': '3434jdfsiu3hk34uh8',
 'IsExternalLocation': False,
 'PrimaryFolder': 'All Locations',
 'SecondaryFolders': [],
 'LastModified': '2021-02-09T06:01:25.0446910+00:00',}
```

I'd like to extract 1 field (Identifier) as a list for further analysis (count, min, max, etc.) but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `locationDescriptions[0]['Identifier']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a syntax feature called "list comprehensions", and you can do something like:

```py
identifiers = [item['Identifier'] for item in locationDescriptions]
```

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-values-of-particular-key-in-list-of-dictionaries) is a small article that gives you more details, and also shows an alternate way using `map`. And [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) is one of the many resources detailing list comprehensions, should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract them with a list comprehension:

```
identifiers = [i['Identifier'] for i in locationDescriptions]
```

You allude to needing a list of numbers *(count, min, max, etc...)*, in which case:

```
identifiers = [int(i['Identifier']) for i in locationDescriptions]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
ids = [locationDescription['Identifier'] for locationDescription in locationDescriptions]
```

You will have a list of identifiers as a string.

Best regards